# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from Canon's EDSDK EdsInitializeSDK() API

Tags: xcode, edsdk

I'm writing a camera control program in Xcode 7.2 on OS X 10.11.2 and every once and a while my program will crash at EdsInitializeSDK(). Most of the solutions online suggest downloading other EDSDK.framework file, but this hasn't worked for me. Also, most of the solutions were written almost 3 years ago.

The thing that doesn't make sense to me is that the program runs most of the time and only occasionally crashes. Has anyone found a work around to prevent the bad access?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to an incompatibility between OSX 10.11+ El Capitan and the "older" EDSDKs, for us when using it in combination with swift. It seems not to be a problem in OSX 10.10 Yosemite. Canon EOS Utility, and other pure objective-c / C++ are mostly unaffected by this. I can confirm that EDSDK 3.4, released Apr 8 2016, includes fixes in this area.

Comment: How do you go about getting EDSDK 3.4? The most recent version on the Developer Portal as of 6/18/2016 is EDSDK 3.2

Comment: EDSDK 3.4 is available on the european portal