# Canon EDSDK Version 3.4 Acquisition

Tags: edsdk, canon-sdk

The Canon EDSDK 3.2 SDK has issues running on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), specifically some type of reference error in the function [EdsInitializeSDK()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611236/exc-bad-access-from-canons-edsdk-edsinitializesdk-api).

I too have had this error on El Capitan and am wondering where to get the latest version of the software EDSDK 3.4 which is referenced in the above linked answer.

I contacted Canon-USA and they said they didn't have it.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: sadly, Canon USA is pretty slow with new SDK versions. As an alternative you can download the newest EOS Utility which uses the 3.4 Dlls. Note that it's not entirely correct to use them from a licensing perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. apply for access to EDSDK via https://www.didp.canon-europa.com/. If your application is successful you'll get a username and password for https://www.didp.canon-europa.com/developer/didp/didp_main.nsf?opendatabase&login

In the download section you'll find the latest EDSDK including version 3.4.

Comment: Hey thanks Wolfgang for the suggestion, however, if you're not physically located in Canon Europe's area of sales this is not an option. They won't give you access.  I've contacted the people at Canon-USA and they have responded saying they will get it to me, yet after literally months, they have not.  I have moved away from Canon's platform.

Comment: Canon seems to be selective about who gets access. My application in 2009 was successful since I applied with my company. 
Some EDSDK code seems to have "leaked" already e.g. by searching for "Written and developed by Camera Design Dept.53" you'll find a link to a  Version 2.8 ESDK for Windows at https://github.com/mengskysama/EDSDK